# converting php array into html

Tags: php, arrays, pinterest

I'm implementing af scraping script for pinterest http://www.zacharydavidbiles.com/2012/05/scraping-pinterest-with-php/ - so far so good, I've succesfully got it running, but I lack sufficient php knowledge in how to parse array into useful html.

```
<?php
    include_once('wp-content/themes/symbol/inc/Pinterest.class.php');
    $pinterest = new Pinterest();
    $pinterest->scrapeUser("casperovergaard");
    $pinterestCovers = $pinterest->getCovers();
    $pinterestThumbs = $pinterest->getThumbs();
    $pinterestLinks = $pinterest->getLinks();

        print_r($pinterestThumbs);
?>
```

What this turns out is a long array of urls from my pinterest

```
Array ( 
    [0] => http://media-cache-lt0.pinterest.com/upload/6544361930035694_2fOhWLC4_t.jpg 
    [1] => http://media-cache-ec6.pinterest.com/upload/6544361930030994_baSRTSh6_t.jpg 
    [2] => http://media-cache-ec5.pinterest.com/upload/6544361929998833_uKTPTrRX_t.jpg 
    [3] => http://media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com/upload/6544361929912044_R8TrDlRF_t.jpg 
) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => http://media-cache-lt0.pinterest.com/upload/6544361930051890_Mjzguspo_t.jpg 
            [1] => http://media-cache-ec2.pinterest.com/upload/106116134940631272_QWvrC09l_t.jpg 
            [2] => http://media-cache-ec6.pinterest.com/upload/92323861080593762_sQGFb6Cw_t.jpg 
            [3] => http://media-cache-ec6.pinterest.com/upload/50806302017302433_3PrHkE8A_t.jpg 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
            [0] => http://media-cache0.pinterest.com/upload/264234703107207356_JWq16vyi_t.jpg 
            [1] => http://media-cache-lt0.pinterest.com/upload/212513676136740135_Xh65hY5R_t.jpg 
            [2] => http://media-cache-ec3.pinterest.com/upload/18225573461849873_hEke4BiA_t.jpg 
            [3] => http://media-cache0.pinterest.com/upload/6544361929985568_HdGFAIaw_t.jpg 
    ) 
    [3] =>
```

So my question is: how do I get this array parsed into lovely images? I've been searching but in vain for an answer.

Comment: use for each loop and then iterate over img src with the links

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you want something and you ask yourself how it is programmed does not qualify as a programming question per-se. Instead search the site for the information you need.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with [PHP's control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php), in particular [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and read the [php manual on arrays again](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). if you already fail to solve this very trivial problem without help, you won't be able to solve any more complex problems either.

Comment: Also, please clarify your array structure. You seem to have an array of arrays there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($pinterestThumbs as $img){
echo "<img src='$img' alt="" title=""/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

somethin like:

```
foreach ($pinterestThumbs as $thumb)
   echo "<img src='$thumb' alt='' >";
```

Notice that the alt attribute is required by the html specification so do not omit it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be

`foreach ( $pinterestThumbs as $url ) {
        echo "<img src='{$url}'/>"
    }`